# Duplicate Row Names Not Allowed

Tags: r

I am trying to load in a set of data into R. It is a text document for a simple stats project.

```
flights<-read.table("flights.txt")
```

however when I do this I am getting the error "Error in read.table("FLIGHTS.txt") : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"

Here is a sample of what the text document looks like.

```
Flight  Plane_ID    Dep_Delay   Taxi_Out    Taxi_In_Arr_Delay
1   N338AA  -2  30  12  -32
1   N329AA  -1  19  13  -25
1   N319AA  -2  12  8   -26
1   N319AA  2   19  21  -6
1   N329AA  -2  18  17  5
1   N320AA  0   22  11  -15
```

I also added in the underscores for the names because I was getting an error pertaining to the number of elements in each line.

After putting in row.names = NULL I am getting this output

```
 row.names Flight Plane_ID Dep_Delay Taxi_Out Taxi_In_Arr_Delay
1          1 N338AA       -2        30       12               -32
2          1 N329AA       -1        19       13               -25
3          1 N319AA       -2        12        8               -26
4          1 N319AA        2        19       21                -6
```

There is an extra set of row numbers and it displays row.names, any way to get rid of this?

Comment: `data.frame` can't take duplicate row names.  It appears that `1 1 1..` are regarded as the rownames.  You could try `read.table('flights.txt', row.names=NULL)`. this will read the `1 1 1` as a column and later you can remove that column

Answer (score 1):

`data.frame` cannot take duplicate row names.  We could use `row.names=NULL` within the `read.table`, which will create an extra column `row.names` that can be removed by subsetting the dataset.

```
dat <- read.table('flights.txt', row.names=NULL)
dat <- dat[-1]
```

Another option would be to use `awk` to replace the first column by `''` from line 2 onwards in the 'flights.txt', `pipe` and read using `read.table`

```
 dat1 <- read.table(pipe("awk 'NR >1{$1=\"\"}1' flights.txt"),
       header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 dat1
 #   Flight Plane_ID Dep_Delay Taxi_Out Taxi_In_Arr_Delay
 #1 N338AA       -2        30       12               -32
 #2 N329AA       -1        19       13               -25
 #3 N319AA       -2        12        8               -26
 #4 N319AA        2        19       21                -6
 #5 N329AA       -2        18       17                 5
 #6 N320AA        0        22       11               -15
```